# Log is full of “stealth mode connection attempt”s

Tags: macos, firewall, udp

My daily log is full of messages like:

> 8/25/12 8:27:01.385 PM Firewall: Stealth Mode connection attempt to UDP 192.168.1.101:40959 from 109.254.109.20:1098

where 192.168.1.101 is IP of my mac. Port 40959 is constant all over messages and "from" addresses vary as well as its port.

I am getting few of those messages every minute. Should I worry about it?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your router to block these attempts (unless the from addresses are local to your LAN).

I would ensure the router's firewall functions are configured properly. If there is port forwarding for port 40959 I would turn that off unless there is a good reason for having it there.